# Suppose that $f$ is continuous and differentiable on the interval $[-7,0]$ that $f(-7)=-3$ and $f’(x)\le 2$. What is the largest value for $f(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous and differentiable on the interval $[-7,0]$ that $f(-7)=-3$ and $f’(x)\le 2$. What is the largest value for $f(0)$?

By the mean value theorem, there exists at least one point $c\in [-7,0]$ such that

$f’(c)=\frac{f(-7)-f(0)}{-7}$

Given $f’(x)\le 2$.

$f’(c)=\frac{f(0)+3}{7} \le 2$

$\implies f(0)+3\le 14$

$\implies f(0) \le 11$

So  the largest possible value for $f(0)$ is $11$.

Is that true, please? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine!
Just a small detail, that c value is in (a,b)

Comment: @user569959 Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to also show that that value can be attained by some function. Maybe there is a better bound that your technique was too crude to find.

Comment: @user647486 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f'(x) = 2$.

Then $f(x) = 2x + c$.

$-3 = f(-7) = 2(-7) + c = c - 14$

$c = 11$

$f(x) = 2x + 11$

$f(0) = 2(0) + 11 = 11$

Comment: The point of this answer is that the proposer showed that $\forall x\in [-7,0]\;(f(x)\le 11)$ but did NOT show that for some $f$ we can have $f(0)=11$.... That is, the proposer did not prove that $11$ is the $least$ upper bound and did not show that the value $11$ could be attained for some $f $..............+1